# Sprite not working/not being displayed (Python/Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Please help me I am starting a game and my sprite is not showing on screen. Take a look, I am using two files, which include pygame and classes. I hope that's enough information.

**Adventure.py** --

```
import pygame, random
pygame.init()
BROWN = (205,192,176)
DEEPBROWN = (139,131,120)
CL = (156,102,31)

from LittleMan import LittleMan
playerSprite = LittleMan(CL, 200, 300)

size = (1000, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Adventure")

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

playerSprite.rect.x = 200
playerSprite.rect.y = 300


carryOn = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while carryOn:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        screen.fill(BROWN)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, DEEPBROWN, [55, 250, 900, 70],0)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        all_sprites_list.add()
        all_sprites_list.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

              carryOn = False

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_x: #Pressing the x Key will quit the game
                    carryOn=False

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    LittleMan.moveLeft(5)
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    LittleMan.moveRight(5)
```

**LitlleMan.py** --

```
import pygame

CL = (156,102,31)
WHITE = (255,255,255)   

class LittleMan (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([50, 75])
        self.image.fill(CL)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, CL, [0, 0, width, height])

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        def moveRight(self, pixels):
            self.rect.x += pixels

        def moveLeft(self, pixels):
            self.rect.x -= pixels
```

Anyone know why this could be? I've looked everywhere but I've done it in two files and no-one seems to have an answer to that and if there is a decent answer please link it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real crux of the problem is the code is not adding `playerSprite` to the `all_sprites_list`.  If a sprite is not in this list, the sprite update and paint calls do not include it.  At first I thought the initial position of the sprite may be off-screen, so I parameterised the screen dimensions, and positioned the sprite in the middle.

There's a bunch of other indentation issues in the question's code too, but I think these may be from pasting the question into SO.

I cleaned-up and re-organised the code, it seems to run, and pressing Left/right moves the brown box.

I merged both files together to make my debugging easier, my apologies.

```
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
BROWN     = (205,192,176)
DEEPBROWN = (139,131,120)
CL        = (156,102,31)
WHITE     = (255,255,255)

WINDOW_WIDTH=500
WINDOW_HEIGHT=500

# Setup the pyGame window
size = (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Adventure")

class LittleMan (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([50, 75])
        self.image.fill(CL)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2 , WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels

# Create the player sprite
playerSprite = LittleMan(CL, 200, 300)

# Add user sprite into PyGame sprites list
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(playerSprite);

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
carryOn = True
while carryOn:

    # Handle user input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_x: #Pressing the x Key will quit the game
                carryOn=False
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                playerSprite.moveLeft(5)
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                playerSprite.moveRight(5)

    # Update and Reapint the screen
    screen.fill(BROWN)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, DEEPBROWN, [55, 250, 900, 70],0)
    all_sprites_list.update()
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The `LittleMan` class does not include an `update()` function, which `all_sprites_list.update()` would normally call.  I expect you just haven't needed this part yet.

EDIT: More notes on the sprite update() function ~

The sprite's `update()` function is called by pygame during the `all_sprites_list.update()` function.  So that means any sprite added to this group, has its update run quasi-automatically.  Ideally all sprites have an update function, and it handles the look, position and collisions (etc.) of the sprite.

The idea behind this function is to do *any* updates to the sprite.  So of you had a sprite that was moving, this function would calculate the next position, and set the sprite's `self.rect`.  Or perhaps that sprite is animated - the update function would set the sprite's `image` to the next frame of the animation based on the time.

Obviously all this work can be performed outside of the update function.  But it provides a simple and *clean* programming mechanism for sprite mechanics.

Comment: Thank you kingsle, please tell me more about the update() function, my sprite isnt moving, My next question will say more.Thanks again (: